# Time constraints on KernelExecute commands or MenuItems?

Tags: front-end, menu

I'm trying to use `Get` to load some pretty substantial packages from a custom menu in the *Mathematica* toolbar (added via MenuSetup.tr).
The problem is, the standard 5-second evaluation timeout seems to apply to commands executed with `KernelExecute`, so only a fraction of my `Get` is evaluated before the command times out.

I'm wondering whether there's an option that can be passed to `KernelExecute` (or to `Item` / `MenuItem`) that will remove that time constraint so that my command can be executed completely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of version 9, `MenuItem` now takes the `Method` option, similarly to `Dynamic` and `Button`.  Which means that you can make it a `"Queued"` evaluation.  To demonstrate:

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "Open", {MenuItem["Delayed New", 
    System`KernelExecute[Pause[10]; NotebookCreate[]], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic]}]]
```

Here we have a command which adds a new menu item after the "Open" menu item which waits 10 seconds, then opens a notebook.  And it fails.  Similar to what you're seeing.  So, let's reset the menus:

```
FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ResetMenusPacket[{Automatic}]]
```

and add it again, but this time with the `Method` option:

```
FrontEndExecute[
 FrontEnd`AddMenuCommands[
  "Open", {MenuItem["Delayed New", 
    System`KernelExecute[Pause[10]; NotebookCreate[]], 
    System`MenuEvaluator -> Automatic, Method -> "Queued"]}]]
```

This has all the same features and limitations of the `"Queued"` usage elsewhere.  For example, if you have a bunch of Shift+Enter evaluations in your queue, this goes to the back of the line and waits for those.

Comment: Fantastic! This allows my menu to function precisely as intended. It's also worth noting that `Method->"Queued"` also seems to allow kernel-blocking dialogs such as `InputDialog` to run from within `MenuItem` without hanging the frontend.